# Is there an inverse Lamperti transformation for diffusions?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

The Lamperti transformation is commonly used to transform SDEs with state dependent coefficients into SDEs with constant diffusion.

For multidimensional processes there are some conditions on the drift that have to be valid before applying the transformation (e.g., drift should be the gradient of  potential).

If we consider a general multidimensional SDE with constant drift
$$ dX_t = f(X_t) dt + \sigma dW_t, $$

can we get the other way around, i.e., can we convert it to a driftless SDE with state dependent coefficient?
If yes, what are the conditions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answered [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434977/is-there-an-inverse-lamperti-transformation-for-diffusions)

Girsanov's applies to state dependent states. So it actually gives simpler answer if initially the volatility didn't depend on the state.

But for changing to a different volatility, the result is false because it changes the quadratic function and thus creates a mutually singular process, see here:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51090/change-of-time-or-change-of-measure

where they consider the event $A=\{\omega:[\omega]_T=a\sigma^2T\}  $ which is $1$ for one process and $0$ for the other.

Now in particular for the Lamperti transform. Following the results 2.1.5/2.1.6 from ["The Lamperti Transform"](https://repository.tudelft.nl/islandora/object/uuid%3A948769c8-49e5-4175-9990-76b3235f7a25) by de Boer,

first using Ito to compute for general map $\psi$.
[image]

then for this specific $\psi$ below, they turn the volatility coefficient to be one.

[image]

So since this mapping is 1-1 we can reverse the above procedure: $\psi$ is invertible and so starting from concrete $Z_{t}$, we can define $X_{t}:=\psi^{-1}(Z_{t})$. This will give the state-dependent diffusion from 2.1.5.